# how to connect ec2 to s3 without using internet access in cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, vpc

I am learning cloud formation so here i want to create infrastructure where access or transfer data between s3 and ec2 instance with out having a internet access for this data transfers,whether i have to define a scripr for this or need to estabish a vpc.
how many ways it will be done.

Comment: Very poorly worded question. Does the ec2 instance have no internet access? What scripts? What do you mean connect to s3? Are you trying to download/upload files to s3?

Comment: yes for both upload and download purpose.

Comment: This is possible and can be done with cloudformation. Article provides information about s3 vpc endpoints https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/

Answer (score 1):

Use VPC end-points or NAT gateways.

Create VPC gateway endpoint in your private subnet where EC2 instacne is present. Then update the route table. You should be able to reach EC2-> S3 without going via Internet Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Might be an old query. But just to add...

You can also use the AWS Interface Endpoint. This will allow your private instances to access S3 without going via the internet gateway (note that DDB is not accessible this way yet).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html